# Where does the class go inside of an anchor Href?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a program in HTML and I am wondering where the "class" keyword goes inside the `<a>` tag with an `href`. Currently, I have it written out as:

```
<a href="Order.html" class = "btn btn-dark">Order Now</a>
```

but am not sure if the class goes before, after, or where I have it currently.

Comment: order doesn't matter - for an a tag, it is standard to put the href first and everything else after, but the standard doesn't care.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the class tag is.

Answer (score 0):

The order does not matter. You can put it wherever you prefer.

Both of these will work fine.

```
<a href="Order.html" class="btn btn-dark">Order Now</a>

<a class="btn btn-dark" href="Order.html">Order Now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any designated order for where the attributes are supposed to go.

---

Normally, for an `<a>` tag, it's a standard to place the `href` attribute first.

```html
<a href="Order.html" class="btn btn-dark">Order Now</a>
```

However, it won't cause any issues if you place `class` first.

```html
<a class="btn btn-dark" href="Order.html">Order Now</a>
```

---

In conclusion, there won't be any differences in the order of attributes. However, it is a standard practice to place `href` first.